# How to control xml from super class for value and attributes using Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
public class ClassA {
    private ClassB classAsB;
...
}

public class ClassC {
    private ClassB classCsB;
}

public class ClassB {
   private String name;
   private String value;
}
```

I have ClassA, where classAsB has name="Joe", value="None"
I would like it to serialize to

`<classA><classAsB code="Joe">None</classAsB></classA>`
**Please note:attribute is code, not name**

I have ClassC, where classCsB has name="www.si.com", value="All"
I would like it to serialize to

`<classC><classCsB url="www.si.com">All</classCsB></classC>`**Please note: attribute is url, not name**

I CANNOT annotate ClassB.

Can this be done via JaxB annotations? If so, please show how